# Async Pages and Handlers

Tags: asp.net

What is the  main benefit of async pages and handlers? Is it that you offload load to a separate thread ? It's not that the user can do other things while the page processes - right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it's not something the user is going to see.

It's so you don't tie up a worker thread waiting for a long-running task to complete.  You might not see much benefit with small sites on an average server, but it does help when the load starts to increase.